# Is it possible to use a Drupal view as input to javascript in a node

Tags: javascript, drupal-7

I have a node which includes javascript which gets data from an external csv file. I would like to get the data from a Drupal view. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup a view that provides the data needed for your javascript to parse and iterate through.

- If all you need is to be able to generate the csv from Views, I'd recommend installing the [Views Data Export module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export).
- However, if you'd rather make your javascript functionality iterate and parse a JSON object rather than a csv, you can also utilize either the [Services Views](http://drupal.org/project/services_views) or [Views Datasource](http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource) modules.

Here's a quick [tutorial blog post with screenshots for setting up a csv data export View](https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2013/05/28/drupal-7-export-view-data-csv-xml-xls-by-views-data-export-module/):

Comment: I want to have the data dynamically derived from a view. I do not want to have to export the data externally. I use csv and json in other maps. But I want the view to be used as the direct source.

Comment: If that's the case, I'd recommend setting up a JSON view and it can serve as a direct source.  No need to export the data externally, just call the endpoint/path you define in the view in your AJAX call.

Comment: Here are two tutorials  for a walkthrough of setting up the JSON view: (1) Using Services/Services Views blog post with screenshots:  https://www.drupalwatchdog.com/volume-4/issue-2/getting-started-services-using-views
(2)  YouTube video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2nHIWlCXSw (at time frame 9:00, it walks through using Views Datasource; and at 30:25, it walks through using Services and Services Views)

Comment: PS- Views DataSource will be the faster/lighter of the two options for setup but isn't covered by the ongoing Drupal Security policy whereas both Services & Services Views are.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into the Services and Services Views.